# How to convert a vector tile protobuf to a png using a stylesheet

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, vector-tiles

I want to convert a vector tile protobuf to a png with customizable styling (like border color, thickness, etc). A solution using Python is preferred, but a solution in nodejs or Linux command line tools are also fine.

I found [this package](https://github.com/mkeller3/mvtToPng) that can do the conversion but without styling options.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "protobuf"? is that actually related here? Seems unlikely ...

Comment: Based on "protobuf", is the source data possibly in [OpenStreetMap PBF format](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PBF_Format)?